# Performance of SimpleXml @ElementListUnion tag over Android

Tags: java, android, performance, serialization, simple-framework

I'm using simpleXml with Android to serialize/deserialize list of objects. Before, I had 30 different objects every one with a class associated that contains the list. To write less duplicate code I've decided use only a class with a list annotated with an `@ElementListUnion` like this:

```
@ElementListUnion({
    @ElementList(entry = "A", inline = true, type = A.class, required=false),
    @ElementList(entry = "B", inline = true, type = B.class, required=false),
    @ElementList(entry = "C", inline = true, type = C.class, required=false)
    })
private List<Object> serializableList;
```

When the element list grows up I have noted that the performance of the deserialization over android falls down. Does exists another form to do that with another annotation or I have to return to the old implementation of my program?

Note: All the elements of my list are of the same type, `serializableList`  can be a `List<A>`, `List<B>` or `List<C>`.

Thanks

Comment: What version are you using, later versions such as 2.7 have much better performance with the ElementListUnion annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate the the class (containing the list) like this:

```
@Root
public class Example
{
    @ElementList
    private List<Object> serializableList;

    // ...
}
```

and the classes (`A`, `B` etc.):

```
@Default
public class A
{
    // ...
}
```

*(Or: class with `@Root` and each Element you need with `@Element`, `@ElementList`, ...)*

With this way you can put everything you need into the list.